# Autofac Module missing Preparing event

Tags: c#, autofac

We have an Autofac module which was created with pre v5 and now that we're using upgraded nuget packages which use v6+ we're getting downgrade errors in the calling project. So forcing the upgrade IComponentRegistration no longer has the Preparing event that we can use in our LoggerModule.
[image]

Does anyone know what needs to be done to make this Module's OnPreparing subscription support version 6+?

Comment: Highly recommended to [check out the release notes on major version upgrades before taking them](https://github.com/autofac/Autofac/releases/tag/v6.0.0). That's for every NuGet package, not just Autofac. Major version increase means breaking changes.

Answer (score 3):

Check the upgrade documentation here: https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/whats-new/upgradingfrom5to6.html

> RegistrationBuilder.RegistrationData no longer exposes the configured ActivatedHandlers, ActivatingHandlers or PreparingHandlers, and IComponentRegistration no longer exposes Preparing, Activating or Activated events.
>
> All Autofac events are now implemented as CoreEventMiddleware added to the resolve pipeline.
>
> If you need to inspect the set of event handlers added to the registration, you can inspect the registered middleware for instances of CoreEventMiddleware:

```
// Check if the registration has an OnActivated handler.
if (registration.ResolvePipeline.Middleware.Any(c => c is CoreEventMiddleware ev && ev.EventType == ResolveEventType.OnActivated))
{
}
```

The new logger example might also help https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/log4net.html: